# Selectively download stackdriver logs from google cloud storage

Tags: logstash, google-cloud-storage, elastic-stack, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'd like to selectively download StackDriver  log files from google storage bucket. The bucket is created for forwarding StackDriver logs and is therefore arranged in a directory fashion i.e. `logs-bucket/cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access/2019/07`.  I am using the [google storage input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage-file_matches). I have achieved something similar with the logstash s3 input plugin for AWS, using the `prefix`  key as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html#plugins-inputs-s3-prefix), see an example below:

```
 s3  {
 "bucket" => "abucket"
 "access_key_id" => "sdsA"
 "secret_access_key" => "mine"
 "prefix" => "AWSLogs/XXXAccountNumber/CloudTrail/us-east-1/2019/07/23}"
 "region" => "eu-central-1"
 "additional_settings" => {
 "force_path_style" => true
 "follow_redirects" => false
    }
 }
```

Is this also possible for dowloading logs from GCS buckets?

Comment: Have you tried using the [file_matches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage-file_matches) property? it is a little different cause it is supposed to be a regex expression, but I think it would provide the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @pessolato I have tried out the `file_matches` feature, unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue.